# How do I reset my ~/profile from the Terminal in Mac OS X 10.5?

Tags: macos, terminal

Greetings,

I recently installed tomcat on my OS X 10.5 box and while I was playing around with the ~/profile I accidentally put in a bad alias and saved it. Long story short every time I open up the Terminal app it tries to launch the alias and hangs up and is unresponsive with keyboard commands.

I tried deleting my Home folder -> Library -> Preferences -> com.apple.terminal.plist

This did not work.... However when I create another user on the system the Terminal works fine.

It's prob some hidden file in the Home directory I assume? But I have had no such luck with rigging my Mac to view hidden files. Please help!

Comment: superuser.com or apple.stackexchange.com would be better places to ask this.

Comment: If you have `root` enabled on the machine (From what I recall, OS X ships with `root` in some sort of disabled state, but you can enable it), you should be able to log in as that and fix your files.

Answer (score 2):

pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> should toggle showing hidden files in finder, without having to use the terminal. Do this, find your .profile file, open it with textedit and fix your mistake.

Comment: Ahh - this may only work in 10.6..

Comment: Only works in file dialogs, not the actual Finder windows. (But still probably the easiest way, all others are destructive or fail with FileVault)

Answer (score 1):

Are you the only user? If so on a new users name (give them admin priveledges) do the following:

```
sudo rm /home/useryoumesseduptheterminalfor/.bash_profile
```

or if its just called '.profile':

```
sudo rm /home/useryoumesseduptheterminalfor/.profile
```

that will remove the file and you will again be able to use terminal without hangups.

Answer (score 0):

You can display the hidden files in the terminal with the following command:

```
cd /Users/newuser  
ls -al
```

All the files which contains a "." in front of the filename, are hidden files..

If you have found the file you need you can view the content with the following command:

```
cat .hiddenfile OR less .hiddenfile
```

Then copy out the things you need for restoring the .profile file.
I hope that's what you wanted..

Answer (score 0):

How about doing:

```
$ sudo mv -i /Users/YourMainAccountName/.profile /Users/YourMainAccountName/busted_profile
```

from the new user you just created?